# Git fetch objects, no refs

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-refspec

I want to fetch objects from a remote repo, but not update any local refs. (Yes, I know this is an rather unusual case.)

I see that I can pass a refspec to `git fetch`, but when I pass an empty one (`git fetch my-remote ''`), it seems to default to something else because I get the following error:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there a way to specify a "null" ref-spec?

Comment: If you don't provide a remote ref, how will it know what to retrieve?

Comment: @larsks, doesn't Git retrieve all objects, regardless of the refspec? Or am I wrong, and Git only retrieves what is needed by that ref.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, which is why that was a comment and not an answer :).  Possibly the protocol description in the git book would yield more answers.

Answer (score 0):

To not update any ref you leave part after `:` in refspec empty:

```
git fetch origin master:
```

Then find the commit hash in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`

Answer to your comment: no, git fetches only objects necessary to get the specified remote ref. The pattern of getting only one branch is commonly used, there is even a dedicated option for `git clone` for this.

PS: I would instead fetch to a temporary branch with some random name.